# MpAndroidChart Line Graph Not displaying all labels

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to add Labels to my Line graph. However, only one label is showing. The examples I'm finding to fix this are for version 2 of MpAndroidChart and I'm currently using version 3.1.

Here is the layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/cumulative_chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:paddingTop="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the code in my fragment to display the graph

```
 fun setLineChartData(linevalues: ArrayList<Entry>,labelsList: ArrayList<String>) {


            val linedataset = LineDataSet(linevalues, "Cumulative Sneezes")
            val legend = binding.cumulativeChart.getLegend()
            legend.textSize = 20F

            linedataset.color = resources.getColor(R.color.green)
            linedataset.setCircleColor(resources.getColor(R.color.green_700))
            linedataset.circleRadius = 5f
            linedataset.setDrawFilled(true)
            linedataset.valueTextSize = 10F
            linedataset.fillColor = resources.getColor(R.color.green_200)
            linedataset.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.LINEAR);

            //We connect our data to the UI Screen
            val data = LineData(linedataset)
            binding.cumulativeChart.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.primaryTextColor))
            binding.cumulativeChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false)
            binding.cumulativeChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false)
            binding.cumulativeChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false)
            binding.cumulativeChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false)
            binding.cumulativeChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false)
            binding.cumulativeChart.xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true)
            binding.cumulativeChart.getDescription().setText("2022 Sneezes")
            binding.cumulativeChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(true);
            binding.cumulativeChart.data = data

            binding.cumulativeChart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(labelsList.size);
            Log.e("labels", "${labelsList}")
            binding.cumulativeChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(IndexAxisValueFormatter(labelsList))
            binding.cumulativeChart.getXAxis().setGranularity(1f);

        //binding.cumulativeChart.xAxis.position  = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM

            // binding.cumulativeChart.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
            binding.cumulativeChart.animateXY(2000, 2000, Easing.EaseInCubic)

    }
```

[I've verified that there is more than 1 label in my array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zrsx.png)

But only 1 label is showing when I load it.
[Only 1 label shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvSKS.png)

- I've tried forcing the number of labels
- I tried adding padding and changing the size of the LineChart

Any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

**Just replace your valueFormatter code with this.**

```
binding.cumulativeChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
        override fun getAxisLabel(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String {
            Log.e("mydata", value.toString())
            var position = 0
            for (i in lineValues.indices) {
                if (value == lineValues[i].x)
                    position = i
            }
            return labelsList[position] ?: value.toString()
        }
    }
    binding.cumulativeChart.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = -90f
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've implemented your code and it is looking better, the correct number of labels are showing. However, they all have the same value as the first entry.

Comment: Are you passing same size of linevalues & labelsList? If not then make sure your linevalues & labelsList size must be same.

Comment: Yes, I verified that they lineValues and labesList are the same size.